# How to get user UID when we send notification cloud function real time database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have function that trigger whenever `onchildadded` and send the notification the subcription users in android. But I have the users UID to store it to the new ref. Actually, I want to send the users UID that have notification.It this possible to do?

```
export const onNotifTugas = functions.database.ref('/tugas_course/{course_id}/{tugas_id}')
.onCreate((snapshot, context) =>{


   //////here i want to get the uid and store it//////

    const course_id = context.params.course_id;
    const tugas_id = context.params.tugas_id;

    console.log(`New Message ${course_id} in ${tugas_id}`);

    return admin.database().ref('/tugas/' + tugas_id +'/').once('value').then(snap => {
            const tugasData = snap.val();
            const notifDataSend = { // buat structure data json dgn nama const notifDataSend untul cloud messaging
                data: {
                            data_type: "tugas",
                            title: "Anda mendapatkan notifikasi baru..", // data bebas (key, value)
                            body: `Tugas ${tugasData.nama_tugas} baru`, // chatId = const chatId
                            sound: "default"
                      }
             };

            console.log(`data yang dikirim `);

            return admin.messaging().sendToTopic(course_id, notifDataSend) 

            .then(function(response) {
                console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
              })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log("Error sending message:", error);
              });

    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    })

});
```